# flat string Message to SampleObject(Some POJO)

Tags: java, string, performance, substring, stringtokenizer

What is the best solution to convert list of string messages as below to list Of SampleObject. I have used substring instead of that better performance alternative solution?

Input msg

```
 List<String> msg = new ArrayList<String>();
     
String str = "ABCD     810121107/09/2021859793 597930091110001110001 000000001USD000000000   000000000   000000000   000000000   2028EN20/28   FR";
String str2 = "ABCD     810121107/09/2021859793 597930091110001110001 000000001USD000000000   000000000   000000000   000000000   2028EN20/28   FR";
msg.add(str);
msg.add(str1);
```

Input msg is List<String> expected output is list of SampleObjects
Here SampleObject contains the properties

```
    publis class SampleObject{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private String date;
    //Have more number of properties

    }
     
    Logic convert List of string to List of Objects

    public List<SampleObject> getObjects(List<String> msgs){
    // Input is List<String> and expected output is List<SampleObejct> by using substring method
    List<SampleObject> sampleList = new ArrayList();
    for(String s : msgs){
    SampleObject sample = new SampleObject();
    sample.id(s.subString(0,9).trim());
    sample.name(s.subString(9,16).trim());
    sample.location(s.subString(16,24).trim());
    sample.date(s.subString(24,26).trim());
    sample.city(s.subString(26,30).trim());
    // like this lot of properties are need to set
    sampleList.add(sample);
    }
    retunr sampleList
    }
```

IS there a better solution instead of using substring to convert list of flat string messages to list of objects? I mean each string convert to object with specific range of string msg to SampleObject properties.
For better solution when dealing with List of billion input strings (msgs)

Comment: You could try splitting based upon one-or-more spaces?

Comment: Here split cont use beacuse first property id 0-9 characters need to capture and 9-16 name from flat string msg like this we have to capture and set to SampleObject properties That is the requirement

Comment: Do spaces matter in your requirements? Also, when you say that 0-9 characters need to be captured, do you mean that first property might have 0 characters - in effect it might be an empty string?

Comment: Yes digvijaykatoch, In my requirement spaces is matter  and we have a valid  value even empty string.
Example input string like ABCDE    000 EXAMPLE
need to split with specific ranges based on requirement like 0-9, 9-11, 11-16 like this etc.. out put string here:- ABCDE    ,00,0 EXAM,PLE